# td content in one line bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Display `td` content in one line using bootstrap. I gone through this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800296/align-elements-in-td-in-one-line) and some more solutions out of [google_search](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=td%20content%20in%20one%20line%20bootstrap), but no luck.

Here is the least HTML:

```
<td class="column-verticallineMiddle">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-mediumItem" >
<span class="pull-right pull-top">Abc</span>
</td>
```

Tried classes without success - pull-right pull-top, inline, etc. I want the text `Abc` to be displayed on the right of textfield.

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8808/)

Comment: What dou you want exactly ? What is the disposition you want ?

Comment: @Seblor - In the last cell of the table td, `textfield` and text `Abc` to be displayed in one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap, you can use inline form from offical documentation.

```
<td class="column-verticallineMiddle form-inline" style="vertical-align:middle;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-mediumItem" style="width:60%;">
    <span>Abc</span>
</td>
```

Just add `form-inline` and determine the input width, see [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssk7833/DTcHh/8818/) Here.

Answer (score 3):

It can also be achieved with `col-xs-8` and `col-xs-4`.

```
<td class="column-verticallineMiddle">
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-mediumItem" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
          <span>Abc</span>
      </div>
 </div>
</td>
```

Have a look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8816/)

Answer (score 2):

try replacing this one..

```
<td class="column-verticallineMiddle" style="vertical-align:middle;">
      <div style="width:60%;float:left;" >
           <input type="text" class="form-control form-mediumItem"> 
      </div>
      <div style="width:30%; float:right;">
           <span class="pull-right pull-top">Abc</span>
      </div>
</td>
```

here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8811/)

Comment: @Sarath- Great, Thanks! But wanted to know if there is any inbuilt css class?

Comment: It's a solution, but if he change the text to something longer, will il still work ?

Comment: @Sarath - Thanks, Let me check.

Comment: yes the width is fixed, long datas can automatically break according to width.. @seblor

Comment: I tried, and actually, the text will be displayed over the input.

Answer (score 2):

I have a working solution :

Create a `div` in your `td`, and use this CSS on it :

```
.inline-td {
    display: flex;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vL6bg109/)

Comment: It displays a box (border around it) can we remove that with border:none; or something else.

Comment: I don't see any border : http://i.imgur.com/3AJDGLj.png (try ctrl + shift + r to refresh the cache)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding a `d-flex` class to the tag did the trick.

```
<td class="d-flex">
  <form action="/dir/delete" method="post">
    <button name="idDelete" th:value="${p.id}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
  </form>
  <form action="/dir/edit" method="post">
    <button name="idEdit" th:value="${p.id}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
  </form>
</td>
```